# mocha: can't use one request for mutlple `it` test

Tags: mocha.js, supertest, vows

```
const request = require('supertest');

const server = request('http://localhost:9001');

describe('Get /static/component-list.json', function() {
    const api = server.get('/static/component-list.json');

    it('should response a json', function(done) {
        api.expect('Content-Type', /json/, done);
    });
    it('200', function(done) {
        api.expect(200, done); // This will failed
        // server.get('/static/component-list.json').expect(200, done); // This will successed
    });
});
```

when reuse `api` in the second test case, mocha will raise a Error:

The result of `mocha test/api` command:

[image: mocha error]

How can I request the url once and use in multiple `it` case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution

You have to create a new request for each test (each `it`) that you want to run. You cannot reuse the same request for multiple tests. So

```
describe('Get /static/component-list.json', function() {
    let api;

    beforeEach(() => {
        api = server.get('/static/component-list.json');
    });
```

Or if you want to reduce the number of requests made, then combine all your checks on the request into a single Mocha test.

#### Explanation

If you look at the code of `supertest`, you'll [see](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/af3c013d84ea019b1af6262b2a056063f2e62ef5/lib/test.js#L87) that when you call an `expect` method with a callback, `expect` calls automatically calls `end`. So this:

```
api.expect('Content-Type', /json/, done);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
api.expect('Content-Type', /json/).end(done);
```

The `end` method is provided by [`superagent`](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), which is what `supertest` uses to perform requests. The `end` method is what kicks off the request. It means you are done setting up the request and want to fire it off now.

The [`end` method](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/b24ab0b0a515a3000ea36b64b4c5fdfdb1407b92/lib/node/index.js#L635) calls the [`request` method](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/b24ab0b0a515a3000ea36b64b4c5fdfdb1407b92/lib/node/index.js#L504), which is tasked with using Node's networking machinery to produce a Node request object that is used to perform the network operation. **The problem is that `request` caches the Node request is produces but this Node request object is not reusable.** So ultimately, a `superagent` or `supertest` request cannot be ended twice. You have to reissue the request for each test.

(You could manually flush the cached object between tests by doing `api.req = undefined`. *But I strongly advise against this.* For one thing, whatever optimization you might think you'd get is minimal because the network request still has to be made anew. Secondly, this amounts to messing with `superagent`'s internals. It may break with a future release. Third, there may be other variables that hold state that might need to be reset together with `req`.)

Comment: Thanks! Your explain is very detailed and useful! Do you know `vows`, which can achieve reusing one request. I will add the code into the question. The problem of `vows` I found is it can't return a useful info for customize test, like `expected: 123, actual: 23` . Maybe I miss something, but I still can't find anything about this from its homepage.

Comment: I think it maybe a issue of `assert`.

Comment: Ok. The problem of `vows` turn out that it use color to spotlight the miss equal thing for `assert.equal`, but without doing it good enough to make user get the message easily. I add two screenshot to explain this in question.

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helpful. You should really ask your question about `vows` in a new question. From your perspective you are trying to solve the same problem ("how do I test my app"), but from the perspective of people reading questions, you are really dealing with two problems.("how can I reuse `supertest` requests" and "how can I use `vows` in this or that way").  Moreover, the community does not see in a good light substantial edits to questions after they've be answered. So I suggest rolling back the edit here and posting a new question.

Comment: Ok. I will do that.